# SQLCODE=-204 when executing in Websphere against jndi db2 data source. "schema.tablename" amalgamated in quotes causing name not found

Tags: spring-boot, db2, websphere

This is similar to [IBM Db2 net driver SQL error. Not finding table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7183433/434145) yet different.

I have a Spring boot JPA app that runs fine from my machine (embedded tomcat) using a datasource configuration

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://**.***.***.209:50001/POTUSDB:securityMechanism=9;sslConnection=true;encryptionAlgorithm=2;sslTrustStoreLocation=/***/***/SSL_Certs/209/209.jks;sslTrustStorePassword=*****;
#spring.datasource.username=DB_USERNM
#spring.datasource.password=*******
```

However when I deploy in Websphere Applcn Server (WAS), and use a JNDI data source,
I notice, the folowing error

> ERROR - 28231 [WebContainer : 1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   - "SNEA_WPI.SNEA_AUTH" is an
> undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.25.25
>       ERROR - 28231 [WebContainer : 1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   - An error occurred during
> implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error
> includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and message tokens
> "SNEA_WPI.SNEA_AUTH".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.25.25

Previously my entity class was annotated with the schema as part of table annotation. When I dropped that and changed it to:
      @Table(name = "SNEA_AUTH")
      I see:

> ERROR - 28231 [WebContainer : 7]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   - "DB_USERNM.SNEA_AUTH" is an
> undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.25.25 ERROR -
> 28231 [WebContainer : 7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   - An
> error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information
> returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-204", SQLSTATE "42704" and
> message tokens "DB_USERNM.SNEA_AUTH".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098,
> DRIVER=4.25.25

As I can run my services and CRUD operations from local, the only way I could replicate this name not found issue in DB2 was changing and running the hibernate query in Squirrel SQL by enclosing the "schmaname.table_name" combination in double quotes.

That causes DB2 to be unable to distinguish between the two tokens.

**My blocker is why this is happening on WAS server when using jndi data source or even spring datasource properties.
while working as expected on local using spring datasource.**

Current props:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/potusdb
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=SNEA_WPI

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was an externalised property file with a db2.jndi property that was used in the code to initialise a DataSource bean.

I discovered it worked when doing a local deployment in was (using locally built fat jar).

This pointed to a different jndi name that would not have contained the schema and table in question.